# Open File/Folder in Drive app (iOS) Through Link

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a way to open a specific file or folder directly from a link on an iPad/iPhone.  We've tested this link (googledrive://) and it opens up the Drive app which gets us pretty close.  The next step would be to add a file or folder id and have it open directly when the link was clicked.  Any ideas on what the parameter may be?

Any help is much appreciated.

Ben

Answer (score 1):

I replaced https with googledrive on my link to a specific document and folder in Google Drive and it worked just fine in iOS.